# Did something changed with next-auth SignIn? (One day it stopped working)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, next.js, next-auth

I've had for months a login page with Next 12.0.10 and next-auth 4.1.2 working perfectly, but lately it stopped working.

I sign in with:

```
  const onSubmit = async ({ email, password }) => {
    try {
      const { ok, error } = await signIn("normal-login", { redirect: false, email: email, password: password, callbackUrl: process.env.LOGIN_CALLBACK_URL})
      console.log('ok, error: ', ok, error)
      if(ok) {
        console.log('Sesión iniciada correctamente')
      } else {
        console.log('error: ', error)
        setCredentialError('Email o contraseña inválidos')
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('error: ', error)
    }
  }
```

But now `{ ok, error }` returns `false` and `sessionRequired` respectively. And `setCredentialError('Email o contraseña inválidos')` is triggered. But the weird thing is that when I refresh the page the login is successful and I'm redirected to my main page. That makes me think that the cookies are set correctly, but something is wrong with my signIn function.

This is my `[...nextauth].js` file:

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth"
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials"
import { login } from "../axios/auth"
import jwt_decode from "jwt-decode";

export default NextAuth({
  // Configure one or more authentication providers
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      id: "normal-login",
      name: "normal credentials",
      credentials: {
        email: {
          label: "Email",
          type: "email"
        },
        password: {
          label: "Password",
          type: "password"
        }
      },
      async authorize(credentials) {
        try {
          const res = await login({
            user: {
              email: credentials.email,
              password: credentials.password
            }
          })

          const { token } = res.data
          const token_decoded = jwt_decode(token)

          const user = {
            id: token_decoded.id,
            email: credentials.email,
            name: token_decoded.full_name,
            role: token_decoded.role,
            image: token_decoded.avatar,
            token: token
          }

          return user
        } catch(error) {
          console.log("error: ", error)
        }
        return null
      }
    }),
    CredentialsProvider({
      id: "admin-login",
      name: "admin credentials",
      credentials: {
        username: {
          label: "Email",
          type: "email",
          placeholder: "nombre@test.com"
        },
        password: {
          label: "Password",
          type: "password"
        }
      },
      async authorize(credentials) {
        try {
          const res = await login({
            user: {
              email: credentials.email,
              password: credentials.password
            }
          })
          const { token } = res.data
          const token_decoded = jwt_decode(token)

          const user = {
            id: token_decoded.id,
            email: credentials.email,
            name: token_decoded.full_name,
            role: token_decoded.role,
            image: token_decoded.avatar,
            token: token
          }

          return user
        } catch(error) {
          console.log("error: ", error)
        }
        return null       
      }
    })
    // ...add more providers here
  ],
  callbacks: {
    jwt: ({ token, user }) => {
      // first time jwt callback is run, user object is available

      if (user) {
        token.token = user.token
        token.uid = user.id
      }
      if (user?.role) {
        token.role = user.role
      }
      if (user?.image) {
        token.image = user.image
      }

      return token
    },
    session: ({ session, token }) => {
      // session callback is called whenever a session for that particular user is checked
      if (token) {
        session.token = token.token
        session.user.uid = token.uid
      }
      if (token?.role) {
        session.user.role = token.role
      }
      if (token?.image) {
        session.user.image = token.image
      }
      console.log('session: ', session)
      return session
    },
  },
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",

    // Seconds - How long until an idle session expires and is no longer valid.
    maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60, // 30 days
  },
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
  pages: {
    signIn: "/user/login" || "/admin/login"
  }
})
```

I've looked if something change with next-auth, but couldn't find anything.
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by upgrading the next-auth library to version 4.18.5.

Answer (score 0):

Just delete

```
NEXTAUTH_URL=blablabla
```

in your `.env` which fixed it for me

Comment: Working locally I could see that this was part of my problem, in my case I did not remove it but changed it appropriately. I had it as 
```NEXTAUTH_URL=localhost:3000``` and I changed it to 
```NEXTAUTH_URL=http://localhost:3000```
The http did the trick for me